# IIR Filter Implementation in C

Tags: c, embedded, digital-filter

I am trying to implement an IIR filter in C for the [FRDMKL25Z](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=FRDM-KL25Z) board. My current code is shown below:

```
#include "Cpu.h"
#include "Events.h"
#include "ADC_1.h"
#include "AdcLdd1.h"
#include "DAC_1.h"
#include "PE_Types.h"
#include "PE_Error.h"
#include "PE_Const.h"
#include "IO_Map.h"


#define NSP 16
static uint16_t DACvalue, ADCvalue;
static LDD_TError Error;
static LDD_TDeviceData *MyDacPtr;
int N=10; // Filter order
double NumCoeff[11]={0.8017, -8.0174, 36.0785, -96.2094, 168.3664, -202.0397, 
                    168.3664, -96.2094, 36.0785, -8.0174, 0.8017};

double DenomCoeff[11]={1.0000, -9.5582, 41.1210, -104.8588, 175.5143, -201.4924,
                    160.6706 , -87.8720, 31.5447, -6.7119, 0.6428};

double Signal[NSP], FilteredSignal[NSP];


int main(void)
{
  /* Write your local variable definition here */
  /*** Processor Expert internal initialization. DON'T REMOVE THIS CODE!!! ***/
    int j, k;
    double y, Reg[NSP];
    PE_low_level_init();
    MyDacPtr = DAC_1_Init(NULL);

    for(j=0; j<NSP; j++) Reg[j] = 0.0; // Init the delay registers
    for(;;){
      for(j=0;j<NSP;j++)
     {  
      for(k=N; k>0; k--) Reg[k] = Reg[k-1];  // Shift the delay register values.

      (void)ADC_1_Measure(TRUE);                /* do conversion and wait for the result */
      (void)ADC_1_GetValue16(&ADCvalue);            /* get the result into value variable */
      Signal[j]=(ADCvalue/65535)*3.5;               /*Convert to volts*/
      Reg[0] = Signal[j];    // The denominator

      for(k=1; k<=N; k++)  Reg[0] -= DenomCoeff[k] * Reg[k];

      y = 0;            // The numerator
      for(k=0; k<=N; k++)y += NumCoeff[k] * Reg[k];
      FilteredSignal[j] = y;

      DACvalue=(FilteredSignal[j]*65535)*3.5; //Convert back to 16 bit 
      Error = DAC_1_SetValue(MyDacPtr, DACvalue);               /* Set DA converter output */
     }
  }
```

Some details of the code:

- I'm using Processor Expert (PE) from freescale to program the embedded board;
- IIR filters coefficient generated using MATLAB;
- As the device needs to filter data in real time I take the minimum required data from the

ADC and filter it through then outputting it to the DAC right after the process;

Once flashed to the board, I get no output from the DAC port whatsoever.

I am open to all suggestions and debugging methods.

Comment: (ADCvalue/65535) <- how does that not underflow?

Comment: actually why do any of that at all? theres no need to do that linear scaling to and from volts at all, just leave it the way it is

Comment: it also looks like your filter doesn't pass DC whatsoever (not just 0dB at DC but -infinity [actually its just like -40]). but you're pulling in an unsigned value, which means the signal you're processing probably has a big DC component you're regecting. worse, you're outputting another unsigned even though the filtered signal is almost definitely going to have negative values. Something is wrong there, but i dont have enough information to figure out what the right thing to do is

Comment: You integer divide a 16 bit value by 65536. That just results in zero, as Steve noticed it.

Comment: Using double precision floating point on a 48MHz Cortex-M0 will be processor intensive.  You should use fixed point arithmetic and preferably 16 or 32 bit. Even using single precision will get you better performance with probably no significant loss of fidelity. You can also improve performance by using DMA to capture blocks of samples and processing an entire block rather than per-sample processing.

Comment: Hey guys,
I understand that there is no need to convert from/to 16 bit resolution any more; the reason I need to work with unsigned is that the DAC works with unsigned data, so as the ADC. I'wont be filtering any negative data because I make my own off-setted signals so I suppose that is ok. Still working on the code so any more suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thank you all, -Nick.

Comment: Offset math is going to be tricky - it can be done, but typically you want to convert to your internal native representation (likely two's complement for this machine) near the input and then back at the output.

Comment: Your FIR portion does not pass DC; the filter output will drift to be centered around 0, and if that is coded into unsigned, you will get wrap-around (-1 will appear as 65535 on an uint16)

Comment: Do you suggest I should design another filter? I just need a simple high pass filter to filter out F(x)=sin(2*pi*80*t)+sin(2*pi*125*t), so I just need the 125 Hz wave out in the end. I got A and B from Matlab and according to simulations it seems to work ok.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you done wrong

- you need to also keep track of previous outputs

  - maybe you were trying to, but the funny nested loop wasn't working
- The denominator is applied to the outputs, not the inputs

  - The denominator is not really the denominator when you apply the coefficients; it's only called that because the frequency response works like a denominator.  The denominator coefficients are multiplied to the history of outputs and their sum is subtracted from the output.  (think of moving all the `y(n-1)... y(n-k)` terms to the other side of the equal sign, leaving only the filter output on one side)
  - The funny denominator coefficient is the that first one, it is multiplied by the new output you're actually trying to calculate!  You will divide your whole result by that one to find out what the new output will be. (in most IIR filters this is 1.0, so you can skip this).
- 16 bit Integer divide by 65535 is zero!, and no need to convert to volts (as others have mentioned).

  - Only do engineering only at the end, and only if you need to; you don't

Here's my suggestion, while trying to keep the same code structure...

```
unsigned int ADCvalue, 
int Reg[NSP]; // use signed values instead of unsigned, and no need for double for history of ADCvalue

for(j=0; j<NSP; j++) Reg[j] = 0; // Init the delayed input registers
for(j=0; j<NSP; j++) FilteredSignal[j] = 0.0; // Init the delayed output registers

for(;;)
{  
     for(k=N; k>0; k--) Reg[k] = Reg[k-1];  // Shift the delay register values.
     for(k=N; k>0; k--) FilteredSignal[k] = FilteredSignal[k-1];

     (void)ADC_1_Measure(TRUE);                /* do conversion and wait for the result */
     (void)ADC_1_GetValue16(&ADCvalue);            /* get the result into value variable */

     Reg[0] = ADCvalue - 0x8000;    // Save the previous inputs samples (and shift the zero value to 0)

     y = 0;
     for(k=0; k<=N; k++) y += NumCoeff[k] * Reg[k];               // The numerator
     for(k=1; k<=N; k++) y -= DenomCoeff[k] * FilteredSignal[k];  // The denominator

     FilteredSignal[0] = y/DenomCoeff[0];

     DACvalue= FilteredSignal[0] + 0x8000;   // shift the zero value back to unsigned, centered at 0x8000
     Error = DAC_1_SetValue(MyDacPtr, DACvalue);               /* Set DA converter output */
}
```

Comment: I didn't test this.  Let me know if it doesn't work and needs a sign change or index adjust.  (i.e., N is not always the same value for numerator and denominator...)

Comment: Hey Michael,
Thanks for answering; I've tried your code but unfortunately it still doesn't work - I get static from the DAC instead of a sinewave that I'm looking for.
I've been following this code to make my own code shown above, maybe
you'd like to take a look: http://iowahills.com/Example%20Code/IIRNthOrderImplementation.txt

I'll keep trying new things, I'll let you know what works.
Thanks again,
-Nick.

Comment: These 2 lines seem to give problems:
    FilteredSignal[0] = y/DenomCoeff[0];
    DACvalue= FilteredSignal[0];
If I remove the first line and replace the second line with DACvalue=y; I get a series of squarewaves. - Nick.

Comment: Just woke up, Will have a look.  BTW, is the adc output signed or unsigned?

Comment: The square wave could be due to incorrect integer wrapping, I changed the ADC to signed values (let me know if zero input on the adc gives 0x0000 or 0x8000).  The output history was not initialized either; edited it.

Comment: Lastly, IIR filters are very very sensitive.  You have the coefficients only to 4 digits which is perhaps not enough (I notice the numerator coefs don't sum to zero!).  You can see this by getting Matlab to show the response of the rounded coefficients. Maybe Try a lower order filter first, and maybe even start with an FIR.

Comment: The ADC outputs in right-justified unsigned; I have created the filter in Matlab, used it to filter out the same signal as in the practical case and 10th order seems to do the trick, any lower and the results weren't good enough. And I choose IIR specifically because the order of the filter is lower compared to the FIR isn't it?

Comment: Yes, lower order than FIR.  Unless you are using the output for more than just the DAC, I'm surprised that you need order 10.  What sort of features does that filter have! (db, ripple...).  At any rate, I recommend using the full 15 significant digits.  The denominator reach very very near to zero; if those coefs are not perfect it might hit zero (zero in the frequency domain I mean).

Comment: Matlab seems to only give me up to 4 points of precision with the command: [B,A]=butter(10,110/5000,'high');
I have choosen my Fs as 10 kHz, honestly I don't know what it depends on when it comes to the microcontroller, if I have a rough idea of the MCUs Fs maybe I can make a simpler filter? I just need a highpass to filter out 125 Hz component.

Comment: You'll need to get matlab to give you more digits; I'm 100% sure that 4 is not enough

Comment: You want to cut 125Hz, but what is the frequency band of the signal you want to keep (250Hz>)?  Generally you set the cutoff at **that** point.  Then depending on how much 125Hz rejection is required you increase the order (cut by 1000? -30db rejection?).  Advanced filters (elliptic??)then talk about pass-band ripple.  We are a bit outside of the scope of stackoverflow now, as well as my expertise.  http://dsp.stackexchange.com would be better (and there I am at best an intermediate).

Comment: Have a look at http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/trad.html, it helps understand what the trade offs are and what you're actually getting.  At least it gives full significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

Second order IIR-Filter Implementation in C:

```
 static double b[] = {1,  -1.4, 1};
 static double a[] = {1, -1.3, 0.5};
 static double v1m1 = 0, v2m1 = 0, v1m, v2m;

 static double iirfilter(double x1) {
    double y1 = 0;
    y1 = (b[0] * x1 + v1m1) / a[0];
    v1m = (b[1] * x1 + v2m1) - a[1] * y1;
    v2m = b[2] * x1 - a[2] * y1;
    v1m1 = v1m;
    v2m1 = v2m;
    return y1;
 }
```