# How to implement IIR filter in C?

Tags: c, pointers, filter

I am trying to implement an IIR filter.

I tried to implement the following filter but

```
FIR : y(n) = b0(x[n]) + ... +bM-1(x[n-M+1])

IIR : y(n) = {b0(x[n]) + ... +bM-1(x[n-M+1])} - {a1(y[n-1]) + ... +aN(y[n-N}
```

I am confused on how to implement `y[n-1].....`.

Here is my code.

```
void IIRFloat(double *coeffs_B, double *coeffs_A, double *input, double *output, int length, int filterLength)
{
    double bcc, acc;
    double *coeffa, *coeffb;
    double *inputp;
    double *outputp;
    int n,k;

    //filter length =7
    for (n = 0; n < length; n++) {
        coeffa = coeffs_A;
        coeffb = coeffs_B;
        inputp = &insamp[filterLength - 1 + n]; //insamp[6]~insamp[85]

        acc = 0;
        bcc = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < filterLength; k++) {
            bcc += (*coeffb++) * (*inputp--); //b[0] * x[6] + b[1] * x[5]...+b[6] * x[0]
        }

        for (k = 1; k < filterLength; k++) {
            acc += (*coeffa++) * (*output--); //a[1] * y[5] + a[2] * y[4]...+a[6] * y[0]
        }
        output[n] = bcc-acc;

    }
}
```

I will not copy here the code for `memove` function for seek of brevity.

Comment: I wonder if this page would help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22765809/1245420

Answer (score 3):

An IIR filter is recursive which means it takes the past values of the output (equivalently it could be expressed as infinite sequence of the input).

Suppose you have the filter

`y[n] = b*x[n]-a*y[n-1]`

Generally the first output is initialized to a given value, for example 0.

Suppose you want to filter the signal x of length `N` then you should do something like:

```
double out[N]; //output vector
double a = 0.3, b=0.5; //assign the coefficients a value
out[0] = 0; //initialize the first element

for (int i=1; i<N; i++)
{
    out[i] = b*x[i] -a*[i-1];  
}
```

In the case of your code I cannot know what you are doing in the line `inputp = &insamp[filterLength - 1 + n];` and that might be a problem.

I will assume `inputp` is the signal you want to filter.

Another issue: you used filter `filterLength` to indicate the lengths of both the input elements and the output elements: that is not generally in a IIR filter.

The output elements from 0 to `filterlength` should be initialized somehow, suppose to 0. Then in the second loop you made the loop index starting from 1 but the coefficient array should start from 0.

(DOUBT: If the oldest element is `y[5]` how can the length be 7?)

Using index instead of dereferencing the array your code should be something like this:

```
void IIRFloat(double *coeffs_B, double *coeffs_A, double *input, double *output, int length, int filterLength)
{
    double bcc, acc;
    double *inputp;
    int n,k;


    for (int ii=0; ii<filterLength; ii++)
    {
        output[ii] = 0;
    }

    //filter length =7
    for (n = 0; n < length; n++) {
        inputp = &insamp[filterLength - 1 + n]; //insamp[6]~insamp[85]

        acc = 0;
        bcc = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < filterLength; k++) 
        {
            bcc += coeffb[k] * inputp[filterLength-k-1]; //b[0] * x[6] + b[1] * x[5]...+b[6] * x[0]
        }

        for (k = 0; k < filterLength; k++) 
        {
            acc += coeffa[k] * output[filterLength-k-1]; //a[1] * y[5] + a[2] * y[4]...+a[6] * y[0]
        }
        output[n] = bcc-acc;

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I think the two `for` being the same length can be merged together:

```
for (k = 0; k < filterLength; k++) 
{
    output[n] += (coeffb[k] * inputp[filterLength-k-1] - coeffa[k] * output[filterLength-k-1]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it with pointers:

```
void filter1(const double *b, const double *a, size_t filterLength, const double *in, double *out, size_t length) {
    const double a0 = a[0];
    const double *a_end = &a[filterLength-1];
    const double *out_start = out;
    a++;
    out--;
    size_t m;
    for (m = 0; m < length; m++) {
        const double *b_macc = b;
        const double *in_macc = in;
        const double *a_macc = a;
        const double *out_macc = out;
        double b_acc = (*in_macc--) * (*b_macc++);
        double a_acc = 0;
        while (a_macc <= a_end && out_macc >= out_start) {
            b_acc += (*in_macc--) * (*b_macc++);
            a_acc += (*out_macc--) * (*a_macc++);
        }
        *++out = (b_acc - a_acc) / a0;
        in++;
    }
}
```

I compared the result of this algorithm to MATLAB's filter function.

**Note**: You can get a large performance gain if you normalize your coefficients (i.e. `a0 == 1`). To do that, you just divide your `a` and `b` vectors by `a0`, and then you don't have to divide `b_acc - a_acc` by `a0` on each iteration.

Comment: in_macc-- will result in access violations when m < filter_length

Answer (score 0):

`y[n-1]` is just the result from the previous time step ex: `output[n-1]` (`y[n-N]` is for the Nth time step from the current one).  So you need to index into the output array by the amount thats appropriate `output[n-k]` (?) (be careful to avoid indexing beyond the beginning of the array however, you'll need code to prevent this).

Also you are not indexing into your coeffa/coeffb coefficients properly (I think). To get the result you want you might need to do this *(coeffa++) to make sure you increment the pointer before you dereference it. I would urge you to do this by indexing into the array directly ex: `coeff_A[k]`, however, as it is much easier to see what is going on.

Last side note: the operation (*output--) is moving the output pointer in a way that I think is unintentional. Index into the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest thing is that afaik u never want to specify A and B separately because B should always equal (1-A).  So, that being said an implementation of a basic IIR filter is:

```
class IIR_Filter
{
    IIR_Filter(double _alpha, double initialValue = 0) 
    { 
        alpha = _alpha; 
        lastVal = initialValue;
    }
    
    double processNextStep(double newVal)
    {
        lastVal = alpha * newVal + (1.0 - alpha) * lastVal;
        return lastVal;
    }
private:
    double alpha;
    double lastVal;
};
```